# SSRS subcription creation date?

Tags: reporting-services, subscription

There seems no created date in subscriptions table in reportserver  database . 
is there any way we can find out when a subscription was created?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it

```
select c.name,s.date_created, * from ReportSchedule rs  
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs s ON s.name = convert(varchar(max),rs.ScheduleID)
JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions sb
ON rs.SubscriptionID = sb.SubscriptionID
JOIN ReportServer.dbo.Catalog c
ON sb.report_oid = c.itemid
ORDER BY s.date_created desc
```

s.date_created is the creation date